# Is the text inside the <p> element considered an inline element?

Tags: html, css, css-float, inline, block

I'm trying to make sense of the CSS float property, and I understand the basic motivation of text flowing around a floated image. My question is this: since inline elements flow around floated elements, even if if those inline elements are children of non-floated block-level elements, can we somehow consider the text inside the paragraph
element to be inline? I'm trying to form a good mental model of what is happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the CSS [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes):

> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element
>   (not inside an inline element) must be treated as an anonymous inline
>   element.

So it's an inline box generated by a block element as opposed to an inline box generated by an inline element. *Anonymous* only means that it doesn't have an associated inline element.

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` is a block element.
`<p>` cannot enclose other block elements.
Text inside of `<p>` is inline by default.

Comment: I'm sure that block-level elements can enclose other block-level elements...maybe I don't understand what you mean by inline-block?

Comment: Yes, you're right, block elements can enclose other block-level elements. However, <p> is an exception to the rule; it's a block element that was never designed nor intended to act as a container for other block elements.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thanks for highlighting that exception, I was not aware of it until now.